# How to fix facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

When I click *share on Facebook button*, I was **directed to** **
[facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_ =_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IjXo.jpg)

All **stop here**. Just a blank page. I have tried various "social share button" plugins and found the same problem on Facebook button. This **happen on mobile** browser. Can I redirect the URL for this action? How to I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just find on the other function. I think **is not the right answer** or its **not fix the problem**. But, all fine after I put this code on function.php on my theme.

```
    // fix share facebook open graph //

//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR USER ID"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="KALTARA CENTER"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="https://scontent-sin6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12743574_1707554466145558_2816765664534740995_n.jpg?oh=e9bac3fd82d2717505136a02c083045e&oe=588CFEF4"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );

the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200), array('class' => 'alignleft'));
```

You can add another answer. I hope you have solution for this issue